# php error with woocommerce Rest api

Tags: php, laravel-5, woocommerce-rest-api

I am trying to add place order in woocommerce with rest api but showing me following error.

> (1/1) HttpClientException cURL Error: Operation timed out after 15000
>   milliseconds with 0 bytes received.

language : php
Framework : laravel

I tried increasing my local php script execution type but it is not working.

Comment: Wherever your calling, is timing out, could be an infinite loop, massive database not indexed, or anything else which might take more than 15 seconds to respond. Check error logs.

Answer (score 0):

This could be caused by following plugins:

Xero
WooCommerce PDF Invoices & Packing Slips